# Best predictor of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Let $B_t$ be brownian motion at time $ t \geq 0$.

Then I want to find the best predictor of $B_8 + 4$ given that there are observations of brownian motion up to time $t = 1$.

Approach:

Essentially, if $X = X_8 +4$, then $Y$ is our observation, we want to find
$\hat X = \mathbb{E}(X|Y)$

So:

$$\mathbb{E}(B_8 + 4 | B_1) = \mathbb{E}(B_8|B_1) + 4$$ since $4$ is a constant.

$$\mathbb{E}(B_8 - B_1 +B_1 | B_1) + 4 = \mathbb{E}(B_8 - B_1|B_1) + \mathbb{E}(B_1|B_1)$$

$$\mathbb{E}(B_8-B_1|B_1) = 0$$ since $B_8-B_1$ is independent of $B_1$.

and $\mathbb{E}(B_1|B_1) = B_1$

Therefore the best predictor is $B_1 + 4$.

Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct, yes. Perharps it would interesting to accompany this result with the standard deviation.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, Tom-Tom, the standard deviation of $B_8+4$ ?

Comment: You have found an estimator, the best one for $B_8+4$. The question I ask is "how good is it" ? Depending on the use you want to make of the estimator, this question can be relevant. The standard deviation $\sigma$ is the answer. You can compute it as $\sigma^2=\mathbb E\left[(B_8+4-\mathbb E(B_8+4))^2\right]=\mathbb E[(B_8-B_1)^2]$.

Comment: Ahh, right. Thanks! I never thought to look at it that way. The variance is 7, and the sd is $\sqrt{7}$. Is this considered "large" ?

Further, could I get insight on how to approach finding the best predictor of $(B_3 - B_2)(B_4 - B_{\pi})$, given an observation of $B_1$ ?